# How to update dropdown menu on click?

Tags: html, angular, typescript

I have a dropdown of “item groups”. It’s successfully loading each item group.

How do I update the item displayed in the drop down? I want to be able to click on a different item group and have that one be selected.

I’m trying to use a “currentItemGroup” variable and update the button on a click. Right now the button isn’t updating when I click a different item group… Is there anything obviously wrong here?

HTML:

```
<div class="btn-group dropup" ngbDropdown title="Item Group">
   <button type="button" class="btn btn-info mr-1 mb-1" ngbDropdownToggle>
     <span class="caret"> {{ currentItemGroup.Name }} </span>
   </button>
   <ul class="dropdown-menu" style="height: 300px; overflow: scroll" ngbDropdownMenu>
     <li ngbDropdownItem *ngFor="let item of itemGroups">
       <button type="button" (change)="onItemGroupSelected(item)" class="btn mr-1">
         <a *ngIf="item.name">
           <p class="small">{{ item.name }}</p>
         </a>
       </button>
     </li>
   </ul>
 </div>
```

Typescript:

```
itemGroups: ItemGroups = new BusinessRuleSets();
currentItemGroup : currentItemGroup = new currentItemGroup();


onItemGroupSelected(itemGroup: ItemGroup): void {
 this.currentItemGroup = itemGroup;
}


loadItemGroups(): void {
this.itemGroups = { itemGroups: [] };
this.currentitemGroup = this.itemGroups[0];
}
```

Comment: the `name` is written with capital `N` and with lowercase `n`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[image: In your code please check the case of variable 'name']

In your code please check the case of variable 'name' as highlighted in above screenshot. You have used 'n' at one place and 'N' at other place. it needs to be in sync.
Refer your object structure and use variable name accordingly

Comment: I fixed the naming convention, but the dropdown still isn't updating on click

Comment: Nvm I fixed the other issue- thank you for the help!